# Permission denied when Map task writes to Hive temporary folder

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera

I'm using Cloudera CDH 4.1 on an Ubuntu Precise 12.04 x64 box. I have used Cloudera Manager Free edition for a smooth installation (after some rough bumps when doing it myself). However, I still can't get Hive to work. Now I can issue Hive QL commands to it to create tables, and load local data (raw table in the examples). But when I try to insert the data into another table (one with proper serde and storage), it fails because of local folder permissions.

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/yaboulnaga/tmp/hive-scratch/hive_2012-11-25_19-22-21_486_4469575874587213091/_task_tmp.-ext-10002
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveFileFormatUtils.getHiveRecordWriter(HiveFileFormatUtils.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.createBucketFiles(FileSinkOperator.java:477)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.closeOp(FileSinkOperator.java:709)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:557)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:566)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecMapper.close(ExecMapper.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:393)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:327)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1332)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
```

I have moved the scratch folder to a folder in my home directory  (as seen in the exception) so that I can chmod it to 777. However, the subdirectories are still owned by hive:hive and mapred:hadoop cannot write to them. I have failed to find any work around for that, and I hope that someone would tell me how to do it right. I have been finding work arounds for the past few days to get Hive to work, and that's on my local machine... I can't even think of how my life would be when I start running it on EC2 as planned.

Thanks folks!

Comment: I tried solving the problem by modifying the umask of the hive user so that it creates writable folders by default.. still no luck

Comment: What user do you run Hive as? I use sudo -E -u hdfs $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive, and chown the relevant files to hdfs. I didn't set up my own environment, though, so I'm not sure if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, am using cloudera udacity VM.
I could create a table, the load data into this table from a external file, and then do a select * from tablename, that's it.Everything else was failing, even select count(1) from tablename, select col1 from tablename etc...
Used the get the same exception, mkdirs failed to create a file at ------------------

I logged out, then logged in back as sudo hive, and all of the sudden everything works like a charm.

Hope this helps !

Comment: thats not proper solution. You have to provide permission for make a dir.